# Can Django have a ManyToMany relationship with global_settings.LANGUAGES?

Tags: python, django

I need my users to be able to state the langue(s) they speak, so naturally I started with:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    languages = models.ManyToManyField("Language", related_name="users")
```

But then I discovered this:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import LANGUAGES
```

Which I'd like to use, if only to keep to the DRY principle.  The problem is, I can't figure out how to allow a user to have multiple languages.

Comment: What does it mean to "have multiple languages"?

Comment: If you need to provide the same contents in several languages, you might want to take a look [django-rosetta](https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta) application.

Comment: I'm just trying to have a list of languages spoken by each user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about...

```
class LanguageSpoken(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey("UserProfile")
     language = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = LANGUAGES)
```

I'm assuming you don't need to keep any other data about the language (like the countries it is spoken in), you just want users to list the languages they speak. If you do need to keep other data, you'll have to use a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: An odd way to draw the lines between objects, but I guess in this case it makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel: Odd? It's just the other way around. BTW, Django has a facility for [following relationships backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).